# What is the root of my application?

Tags: filesystem, root

Can someone help me understand what is the root of my application?

I would like to use vim and create a one line procfile in the root of my application.

Then I can test the procfile using a gem called foreman with the following command in my terminal:
foreman start

I have tried sudo vim /procfile
and created the file and saved it in what I thought to be the root.
Then I typed:
foreman start
and the response is that Procfile does not exist.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you creating a Rails app? If so the "root" of your application is the folder you created with the 'rails new' command. So, if you save all your rails projects in your home directory in a folder called rails_apps for example, it's ~/rails_apps. If you create a new rails app there called newapp, your application root directory is ~/rails_apps/newapp.

Comment: Thanks @JaysonRowe that is most helpful .... I will try and get the gem foreman to test this out.

Comment: It worked ... and I also had to change the command 'foreman start' to "foreman start -f" in the root. .... thanks.

Comment: My Pleasure, Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relation to filesystems or drives, root is usually the topmost directory on the drive, or / - the root file system. Your applications should not have roots. ;)

PS: Wikipedia has a better explanation:

https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Root_directory

Comment: Thanks mikewhatever .... that explains why I am getting nowhere with this line of attack ... I will look more closely at other strategies.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)